# matplotlib grouping values of x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, seaborn

I'm having a very weird behavior in matplotlib+seaborn.

**Please, never mind aesthetic features!**

I have a .csv file which rows have very small values

The read of csv is with pandas:

```
csvdata = pd.read_csv('csv.csv', sep=';', header=None, index_col=0)
idx = np.arange(1, 33)
y = csvdata.iloc[4,idx]
x = csvdata.iloc[0,idx]
```

Each line of that file is my 'y', and has values as:

```
0.000001479;0.000001562;1.47E-06;1.39E-06;1.35E-06;1.36E-06;1.33E-06;1.30E-06;1.25E-06;1.26E-06;0.000001249;1.23E-06;1.21E-06;1.19E-06;1.17E-06;1.18E-06;1.17E-06;1.12E-06;1.11E-06;1.10E-06;1.11E-06;1.10E-06;0.000001073;0.000001055;1.05E-06;1.05E-06;1.03E-06;1.02E-06;1.02E-06;1.01E-06;1.01E-06;1.01E-06
```

An the 'x' is:

```
0.223214286;0.446428571;0.669642857;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4;4;5;5;5;5;6;6;6;6;6;7;7;7
```

When I try to plot that row in matplotlib, it gives me:

[image]

As one can see, the plot is grouping a lot of values. I tried to set the xaxis values in order to make it corret, so I did:

```
fig = sb.plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, '-o', color='orange', linewidth=3)

fmt = tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%1.1E')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
fmt = tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%1.2f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.MultipleLocator(.22))
```

And the result:

[image]

And what I want is (exported from Excel):

[image]

Any idea of whats is causing this problem? In my opinion, it shold be as simple as: plot(x,y) and the matplotlib should identify all values in both axis...

Did I miss something?

In advance, thank you all!

Comment: I assume the data that you pasted above is what you define as `y`? What is your `x` here? I suspect that's where your problem is

Comment: @tom, I'll update my questinon adding the information of x and y...

Comment: Can you edit the question with a sample for the x (as you did for the y) ?

Comment: @tmoreau, sure, I'll do that.

Comment: @tmoreau I see now that my problem is on x vlaues! I'll try to fix it!

Comment: Well of course your values will group together: look at your `x` values after the first 3: `1;1;1;2;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4;4;5;5;5;5;6;6;6;6;6;7;7;7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some suggestions of @tom and @tmoreau, I saw that problem was on the values o x!

**Thank you guys!**

That data of csv is exported from excel and if the "Number format" there doesnt have precision, it will export the data as truncated values!

After the fix, I have the x values:

```
0.22321428571428600000;0.44642857142857100000;0.66964285714285700000;0.89285714285714300000;1.11607142857143000000;1.33928571428571000000;1.56250000000000000000;1.78571428571429000000;2.00892857142857000000;2.23214285714286000000;2.45535714285714000000;2.67857142857143000000;2.90178571428571000000;3.12500000000000000000;3.34821428571428000000;3.57142857142857000000;3.79464285714286000000;4.01785714285714000000;4.24107142857143000000;4.46428571428571000000;4.68750000000000000000;4.91071428571428000000;5.13392857142857000000;5.35714285714286000000;5.58035714285714000000;5.80357142857143000000;6.02678571428571000000;6.25000000000000000000;6.47321428571428000000;6.69642857142857000000;6.91964285714285000000;7.14285714285714000000
```

And the ploting works like a charm:

[image]